# how to use Adaboost algorithms from Weka library in Jython

Tags: python, jython, weka

I use Weka classes in Jython, the problem is how can define the classifier of Adaboost.

I use:

import weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1 as AdaBoost

But I do not know how can adjust its classifier for example set J48.

Answer (score 1):

This jython code worked for me in 3.7.10

```
algo = AdaBoostM1()
option_string = " -P 100 -S 1 -I " + str(num) + " -W weka.classifiers.trees.J48"
options = splitOptions(option_string)
algo.setOptions(options)
algo.buildClassifier(data)
```

You can also do it like this:

```
algo = AdaBoostM1()
options = [];
options.append("-P");
options.append("100");
options.append("-S");
options.append("1");
options.append("-I");
options.append(str(num));
options.append("-W");
options.append("weka.classifiers.trees.J48");
algo.buildClassifier(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost every classifier in weka can be used from command line. This command line usage is provided to java users with option handler interface. See [Use WEKA in your Java code](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code).

```
Option handling
Weka schemes that implement the weka.core.OptionHandler interface, 
such as classifiers, clusterers, and filters, offer the following methods 
for setting and retrieving options:
```

According to this , you will use following java code:

```
import weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1;

AdaBoostM1 classifier = new AdaBoostM1();
Instances data = readArffFile();
String optionString = " -P 100 -S 1 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.trees.DecisionStump";
classifier.setOptions(weka.core.Utils.splitOptions(optionString);
classifier.buildClassifier(data);
```

I am afraid, you need to change this java code to jython. I do not think , it will be hard.